# Let $A=\{(x,y) : x \in \mathbb{Q}, y \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Show that $m(A)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $A=\{(x,y) : x \in \mathbb{Q}, y \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Show that $m(A)=0$.

We notice that $A = \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R}$. Now since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable we can denote it as $\{x_1,x_2, \dots \}$. Now consider the intervals $\{(x_n-\frac{\varepsilon}{2^k}, x_n + \frac{\varepsilon}{2^k}) \times (k-1, k+1)\}.$

I can show that the sum of the lengths of these intervals is zero as $$\ell(I_k)=\frac{4\varepsilon}{2^k}$$ so $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell(I_k) = 4\varepsilon$$

but I don't know how can I show that the intervals cover $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R}?$

Comment: You could also consider $$A_n=\Bigg\{(x,y):|x-q_n|<\frac{\epsilon\cdot e^{-y^2/2}}{2^{n+1}\sqrt{2\pi}}\Bigg\}$$ to prove this directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to conisder $(x_n-\frac {\epsilon} {2^{k+n}},x_n+\frac {\epsilon} {2^{k+n}})\times (k-1,k+1)$. Both $n$ and $k$ are varying.

If $q \in \mathbb Q$ and $ y \in \mathbb R$ then  there exist $k$ such that $y \in (k-1,k+1)$ and $q=x_n$ for some $n$.  Hence, $(q,y) \in (x_n-\frac {\epsilon} {2^{k+n}},x_n+\frac {\epsilon} {2^{k+n}})\times (k-1,k+1)$. Now check that the total measure of all these intervals is less than $4\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

Your set is a countable union of copies of the real line (indexed by $\mathbb{Q}$). The two-dimensional measure of a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is zero so your total measure is zero by countable additivity